# Disable button inside a GridView TemplateField

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following gridview control

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlBeforeSave" Visible="true">
<asp:GridView ID="gvP" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="false"
  AllowSorting="false" CssClass="list-table" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header">
  <Columns>

  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
  ItemStyle-CssClass="unsortable">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <input id="btnPay" type="button" onclick="javascript:OpenEditPaymentItemDialogPage('<%# Eval("PmtId") %>');"
   value="Edit" class="button save" style="width: 80px" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

After I save the griview dataset to Database I have to disable the griview.
but btnPay still enabled. I need to do it from code behind
Any idea?

Comment: Where did you placed the code that save the data? you can immediately find control and set disabled to true in that row `(HtmlInputButton)row.FindControl("btnPay").Disabled=true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am done it.

C#

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "HidePaymentItemButtons", "javascript:disableAllButtons_PT;", true);
```

JS

```
        function disableAllButtons_PT() {
        var gridViewID = "<%=gvPamentItemsList.ClientID %>";
        var gridView = document.getElementById(gridViewID);
        var gridViewControls = gridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (i = 0; i < gridViewControls.length; i++) {
            // if this input type is button, disable
            if (gridViewControls[i].type == "submit") {
                gridViewControls[i].disabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make input type="button"  to accessable on code behind side by adding use of RunAt="Server" element

so you code will be like

```
<ItemTemplate>   
<input ruat="server" id="btnPay" type="button" onclick="javascript:OpenEditPaymentItemDialogPage('<%# Eval("PmtId") %>');"    value="Edit" class="button save" style="width: 80px" />  
  </ItemTemplate>
```

or make use of `Asp:Button`

```
<ItemTemplate>   
<asp:button ruat="server" id="btnPay" type="button" onClientclick="javascript:OpenEditPaymentItemDialogPage('<%# Eval("PmtId") %>');"    value="Edit" class="button save" style="width: 80px" >   </asp:button>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Than make use of `RowDataBound` event of datagridview and disable button..

Comment: If I add it I get a sever error that this line is not well formatted.

Comment: @Nilaa you get it because of the onclick format. try this way: onclick='javascript:OpenEditPaymentItemDialogPage(<%# Eval("PmtId") %>);'

Comment: Yes .. Now ok. but how to make use of RowDataBound to disable the buttons. I just need to disable the whole page after I save page data. the save button is in the bottom of the page, before I save page data, I can be able to edit records in the griview.

Comment: @Nilaa - make check on google u will find a lot about rowdatabound and disabling controls.....

Answer (score 0):

After you save data, put the following code. I have tested. onlcick is disabled.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvP.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   HtmlInputButton btn = (HtmlInputButton)gvP.Rows[i].FindControl("btnPay");
   if (btn != null) btn.Disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes.. tried, other than the button inside the griview others are disabled.

Comment: Hello, I just copy your aspx codes and bind data to gridview. After bind, I put pnlBeforeSave.Enabled = false; then button also disabled.

Comment: Did you add a onclick event and try to the button?

Comment: Oh yes, even button is disabled, onclick event is invoking.. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can use,

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPay" runat="server" OnClick="btnPay_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" Text="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PmtId") %>'/>

public void btnPay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "key", "<script>OpenEditPaymentItemDialogPage('" + button.CommandArgument + "');</script>");

}
```